# Divide circle image into 4 slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have this image:

[image: circle image 4 slice]

Now, what I want to achieve is: when the mouse hover a particular slice, that slice will becames a little bigger and the rest of the circle will blur.

I really can't get an idea how to do that, even with Javascript, JQuery and CSS! Maybe I could map the image, but I still have some doubt how to achieve what I need.

The 4 different color of my circle image will be 4 different image, so I can both photoshop them together or use HTML to make them appear like a circle.. I can use both of this solution.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english >_>

Comment: If you already have each slice as a separate image, I'd use four `<img>` elements with appropriate CSS to stick them together, and then do the enlarging and blurring either with `:hover` and sibling selectors in CSS or maybe a jQuery hover handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done CSS-only :D

You'll make a wrapper containing the four quarters. By setting the border-radius on one corner per quarter, you'll create the circle.
On `:hover` you can change the size using `transform: scale();` and the blur using `opacity` when `.wrapper:hover .quarter`.

```css
div.wrapper { position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius: 50px; }
div.quarter { position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #333; transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s; }
div.quarter.left-top { left: 0; top: 0; border-top-left-radius: 50px; }
div.quarter.right-top { left: 50px; top: 0; border-top-right-radius: 50px; }
div.quarter.left-bottom { left: 0; top: 50px; border-bottom-left-radius: 50px; }
div.quarter.right-bottom { left: 50px; top: 50px; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px; }
div.wrapper:hover div.quarter { opacity: .5; }
div.quarter:hover { opacity: 1 !important; transform: scale(1.5) }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="quarter left-top"></div>
  <div class="quarter right-top"></div>
  <div class="quarter left-bottom"></div>
  <div class="quarter right-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go, you achieve it only with css.

wrap all of your four divs in one `.container` then give them same `height` and `weigth`
i.e: `.scale{height: 150px; weight 150px}` and to make a quarter of circle you need to add `border-radius` property. after that you need to handle the `hover` event by

```
.scale:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 100;
    filter: blur(0) !important;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0) !important;
}
.container:hover .scale{
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.scale{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
div#one {
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/150.png/09f/fff);
  -moz-border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 150px 0 0 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
div#two{
   background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/150.png/f00/fff);
  -moz-border-radius: 0 150px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 150px 0 0;
  right: 0;
}
div#three{
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/150.png/f60/fff);
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 150px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 150px 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
div#four{
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/150.png/000/fff);
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 150px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 150px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.scale:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 100;
    filter: blur(0) !important;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0) !important;
}
.container:hover .scale{
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scale" id="one"></div>
  <div class="scale" id="two"></div>
  <div class="scale" id="three"></div>
  <div class="scale" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a bit late to the party :p

Comment: @BillyNate +1 for both answers, but John's is closer to the mark, since it uses images, like the OP indicated.

Comment: True that! I'll keep [dummyimage.com](http://dummyimage.com) in mind for next time and upvote this answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use 4 separate images to display your image positioned with css
then add an onmouseover to each image to change its width and height

example

```
<img src='grey_quadrant' id='grey' width=100 height=100 style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px' onmousover='this.width=120; this.height=120'>

<img src='red_quadrant' id='red' width=100 height=100 style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left:100px' onmousover='this.width=120; this.height=120'>

<img src='blue_quadrant' id='blue' width=100 height=100 style='position: absolute; top: 100px; left:0px' onmousover='this.width=120; this.height=120'>

<img src='brown_quadrant' id='brown' width=100 height=100 style='position: absolute; top: 100px; left:100px' onmousover='this.width=120; this.height=120'>
```

Or you could do something similar with svg

A quick and easy way to blur the other 3 quadrants is to include that in the mouseover as well, say for the red quadrant that becomes

```
onmousover='this.width=120; this.height=120; document.getElementById("blue").src="blurred_blue_quadrant.jpg"; document.getElementById("grey").src="blurred_grey_quadrant.jpg";document.getElementById("brown").src="blurred_brown_quadrant.jpg"'
```

in order to restore the original images use an onmouseout for each img tag
in the case of the red quadrant add an onmouseout like

```
onmouseout='this.width=100; this.height=100; document.getElementById("blue").src="blue_quadrant.jpg"; document.getElementById("grey").src="grey_quadrant.jpg";document.getElementById("brown").src="brown_quadrant.jpg"'
```

It would require you to have both blurred and unblurred images for each quadrant
If you want to do something fancier with blurring you could use SVG or CSS